# Use offline Jenkins Slaves to access GIT through master

Tags: git, jenkins

Let's say I have two Jenkins Instaces:

- one, which is allowed to access some GIT Server
- another one which can't reach the internet at all

Is there any possibilty to pull a GIT repository on the master node and use the content on the slave nodes even though the repository can't be reached from there?

Generally this should be possible by copying the content after "git pull" on master to the slave.

Is there a simple/recommended way to achieve this?

I've seen "GIT Server" Plugin, but I wasn't able to find a solution to use it on a slave with the master as origin.